# Regex match can't separate value and text

Tags: .net, regex, f#

```
            let IntAndString value = 
                let (|Match|_|) pattern input =
                    let m = Regex.Match(input, pattern) in
                    if m.Success then Some ([ for g in m.Groups -> g.Value ]) else None
                match value with
                    | Match "(\d+)(\w+)" x  -> Some(x)
                    //| Match "(\w+)" x       -> Some(x)
                    | Match "(\d+)" x       -> Some(x @ ["items"])
                    | _                     -> None
```

So I want

```
10a   -> 10 , a  it works 
100a  -> 100 , a doesn't works - no idea why
100   -> 100 , items doesn't works
```

why 100a -> 100, a doesn't works and how can I realize it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd the second match clause to be used when the string contains just numbers (and the first one when there are numbers followed by letters).

The problem is that the `\w` class apparentely also contains numbers (you can try it using a simple pattern), so when you match `10` against `\d\w` the engine assigns `1` to `\d` and `0` to `\w`.

You can try something simple like this:

```
let IntAndString value = 
  match value with
  | Match "([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)" x -> Some(x)
  | Match "([0-9]+)" x          -> Some(x @ ["items"])
  | _                           -> None     

IntAndString "100"
```

Documentation for [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) should explain the behavior you encountered.

Comment: Quantifiers are greedy unless you have a `?` after it, so the `\d+` should catch everything up to the first non-digit, leaving `\w` to catch all letters and numbers afterward.  I am wondering if the regex should have `^` and `$` though, and if the `\w` should be a `.`.

Comment: @YotaXP - that's not quite right.  although the `\d+` will try to match the longest possible substring first, it will still backtrack.  Thus, when matching `\d+\w+` against `"100"`, the `\d+` will attempt to capture the whole string.  However, when that doesn't leave any characters left for the `\w+`, backtracking will kick in, matching the `\d+` against `"10"`, leaving the `"0"` for `\w+`.  For a true greedy (non-backtracking) match, you can use `((?>\d+))(\w+)`.

Comment: note that your solution has different behavior than the original in that the digit class contains Unicode characters which indicate digits in other cultures as well (e.g. the Arabic-Indic Digit Zero `'٠'`), which may or may not be desired.  To match the original, `@"(\d+)([^\d]+)"` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like 
    Match "(\d+)(\w*)"
'cause the + means 1 times or more.
the * means 0 times or more.